# Laravel order by highest number

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to order the highscores from high to low like this:

```
$highscores = HighScore::orderBy('score', 'asc')->get();
```

But everything is all over the place. What could be the problem?

Comment: If you want it from high to low, why using order by `asc` ? Isn't it supposed to be `desc` ?

Comment: desc, but if everything is all over the place, maybe your score field is a string instead of a number? Which means that it will sort on alphabet

Comment: May I have your example data set on which you are applying order by ?

Comment: Yes, made score as a string oepss..

Answer (score 1):

it should be 
`$highscores = HighScore::orderBy('score', 'desc')->get();`